# Iterating and Manipulating Strings in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, indexing

What I'm trying to do should be simple, but I can only come up with verbose solutions thanks to Swifts handling of string indices and characters. Basically I have a large list of instructions, stored as an array of strings. Example values are:

```
"1) Do this thing"
"2) Do that thing"
```

I want to remove the numbering (e.g. `"1) "`) from these strings so that I can create my own formatting later when I add the strings to a `UITextView`.

I have been able to get the following code to work:

```
func removeNumbering(from instruction: inout String) {
    var indexOfFirstLetter = 0

    for (index, character) in instruction.unicodeScalars.enumerated() {
        if NSCharacterSet.letters.contains(character) {
            indexOfFirstLetter = index
            break
        }
    }

    let range = instruction.startIndex ..< instruction.index(instruction.startIndex, offsetBy: indexOfFirstLetter)
    instruction.removeSubrange(range)
}
```

Is there a more concise way to do this? Seems like I should be able to remove characters until the loop finds the first letter, but getting access to both the `unicodeScalar` and the `String.Index` from within the loop has proven difficult.

Any suggestions or improvements on this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var s1 = "1) Do this thing"
var s2 = "2) Do that thing"

s1.characters.removeFirst(3)
print(s1) // prints "Do this thing"

s2.characters.removeFirst(3)
print(s2) // prints "Do this thing"
```

If you need more elaborate trimming, use regular expression:

```
s1.replacingOccurrences(of: "[0-9]\\) ", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
print(s1) // prints "Do this thing"
```

Comment: All these answers are great, but I'll go ahead and accept this one due to its brevity. Using your `replacingOccurrences()` answer, I can just `map(_:)` the numbered instruction array to a new array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the strings, presuming they all follow the same pattern with a space directly before the first letter, this method is one solution:

```
extension String {
    var strip: String {
        var copy = self
        for c in copy.characters {
            guard c == " " else { continue }
            copy.removeSubrange(copy.startIndex...copy.characters.index(of: c)!)
            break
        }
        return copy
    }
}

"1) Do something".strip    // "Do something"
"1234567890 Text".strip    // "Text"
```

Obviously this method isn't safe if the strings have patterns that conflict with the above presumption.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

```
    let s1 = "1) Do this thing"
    let s2 = "201) Do that thing"

    func stripNumber(_ s:String) -> String? {
        let reg = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\d+\\) ")
        if let tm = reg.firstMatch(in: s, range:NSMakeRange(0,s.utf16.count)) {
            return (s as NSString).substring(from: tm.range.length)
        }
        return nil
    }

    print(stripNumber(s1)!) // Do this thing
    print(stripNumber(s2)!) // Do that thing
```